# TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when calling a method from another class

Tags: python, list, optimization, types

I'm writing a code for an optimisation problem based on library found here [metaheuristic-algorithms-python 0.1.6](https://pypi.org/project/metaheuristic-algorithms-python/). I have 2 classes

- Search_FA: A python script I wrote to create an object with some parameters and pass it to the 2nd class below
- FireflyAlgorithm : a class that implements searching based on Firefly optimisation algorithm developed in the metaheuristic-algorithms-python 0.1.6 and I did not change it

---

Class #1:

```
 from metaheuristic_algorithms.firefly_algorithm import FireflyAlgorithm
rosenbrook_function_wrapper = MyObjective()

Location = [8,2,2,10]

Light = 0.95

number_of_fireflies = 10
maximun_generation = 10 
randomization_parameter_alpha = 0.2 
absorption_coefficient_gamma = 1.0
result = FA_search.search(number_of_fireflies,maximun_generation,randomization_parameter_alpha,absorption_coefficient_gamma)
```

Class#2:

And here is the method I'm invoking *search* from the imported class FireflyAlgorithm

```
def search(self, number_of_fireflies = 10, maximun_generation = 10, randomization_parameter_alpha = 0.2, absorption_coefficient_gamma = 1.0):

        self.__initialize_fireflies(number_of_fireflies)

        for generation in range(maximun_generation):

            for firefly in self.__fireflies:
                firefly.update_light_intensity()

            self.__move_fireflies(randomization_parameter_alpha, absorption_coefficient_gamma)

        solution_firefly = self.__select_best_firefly_by_light_intensity(self.__fireflies)

        return { "best_decision_variable_values": solution_firefly.location_coordinates, "best_objective_function_value": solution_firefly.light_intensity }
```

however when I run my code I get this error

```
        File "Search_FA.py", line 34, in <module>
    result = FA_search.search(number_of_fireflies,maximun_generation,randomization_parameter_alpha,absorption_coefficient_gamma)

  File "\metaheuristic_algorithms\firefly_algorithm.py", line 32, in search
    self.__initialize_fireflies(number_of_fireflies)

  File "\metaheuristic_algorithms\firefly_algorithm.py", line 50, in __initialize_fireflies
    decision_variable_values = [super(FireflyAlgorithm, self).get_decision_variable_value_by_randomization(variable_index) for variable_index in range(self.number_of_variables)]

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

All variables I passed are *int* so I wonder from where is *list* coming?